# Облегающий внешний контейнер

Tags: html, css, css3

Как заставить внешний контейнер q2 заставить облегать блоки находящиеся в нём?. Можно указать width:308px пикселов, но есть ли свойство которое автоматом всё делает? https://jsfiddle.net/1ht5mo7o/1/

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.q1 {
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
}

.q2 {
  border: 1px blue solid;
  width: 308px
}
```

```html
<div class="q1">
<div class="q2">
<p></p> 
<p></p> 
<p></p> 
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Наиболее кроссбраузерно:

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.q1{
  height:400px;
  border:1px black solid;
  text-align:left; /* <--------- */
}

p{
  vertical-align:top;
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background:black;
}

.q2{
  border:1px blue solid;
  display:inline-block; /* <--------- */
}
```

```html
<div class="q1">
  <div class="q2">
    <p></p> 
    <p></p> 
    <p></p> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Наиболее современно

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/min-width#Browser_compatibility
http://caniuse.com/#feat=intrinsic-width

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.q1{
  height:400px;
  border:1px black solid;
  text-align:center;
}

p{
  vertical-align:top;
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background:black;
}

.q2{
  border:1px blue solid;
  width:-moz-min-content; /* <--------- */
  width:min-content;      /* <--------- */
  white-space:nowrap;     /* <--------- */
}
```

```html
<div class="q1">
  <div class="q2">
    <p></p> 
    <p></p> 
    <p></p> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Очень слабая поддержка браузерами `width: min-content;`  http://caniuse.com/#feat=intrinsic-width

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, да. В ответе есть ссылка на аналогичную таблицу на MDN. Добавил и эту.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать с помощь `inline-flex`:

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.q1 {
  height:400px;
  border:1px black solid;
}

p {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}

.q2 {
  border:1px blue solid;
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="q1">
<div class="q2">
<p></p> 
<p></p> 
<p></p> 
</div>
</div>
```

Если надо отступы между тэгами `p` просто добавьте:

```
p + p {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```